# R Error: could not find function "select"

Tags: r

`select(data, starts_with("nase"))`

Which package do I need to use the select function?
How can I find out? Google, stackoverflow is not helpful atm.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Please rewrite your question to explain intended outcome and provide some example data.

Answer (score 9):

You're right that `select` is hard to look up:

```
library(sos)
findFn("select")
```

returns 7184 hits.

But you could always try

```
findFn("starts_with")
```

which gives only 14 hits in 9 packages, the first one of which leads to `dplyr::select`.

The other strategy would be to try to find clues in whatever place you found this code fragment in the first place ...

Answer (score 6):

I think, it should be the library dplyr

please see this link: http://rpackages.ianhowson.com/cran/dplyr/man/select.html

Comment: the link is broken it seems.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install package dplyr by running the command below:

   ```
   install.packages("dplyr")
   ```
2. After this, load the library using the command below:

   ```
   library(dplyr)
   ```